# How clear many to many relation table on delete entity

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How make autoclear relation table when one of entity deleted ? Now when I delete task or type in relation table `tasks_types_realations` still exist record with id of deleted entity, for example I have task with id: 1, and type with id: 1, in relation table it will `|taskId:1|typeId:1|`, and after delete task or type record still exist.

Task model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Task = sequelize.define('task', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['done', 'pending', 'cancel'],
      defaultValue: 'pending',
      allowNull: false
    },
    date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    },
  })

  Task.associate = models => {
    Task.TaskType = Task.belongsToMany(models.TaskType, {
      as: 'types',
      through: models.TasksTypes
    })
  }

  return Task
}
```

Type model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const TaskType = sequelize.define(
    'taskType',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
      }
    },
    {
      tableName: 'tasks_types'
    }
  )

  TaskType.associate = models => {
    TaskType.Task = TaskType.belongsToMany(models.Task, {
      as: 'tasks',
      foreignKey: 'typeId',
      through: models.TasksTypes
    })
  }

  return TaskType
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In task model add:

```
Task.TasksTypes = Task.hasMany(models.TasksTypes, {
  as: 'typesRelations',
  foreignKey: 'taskId',
  hooks: true,
  onDelete: 'cascade'
})
```

In type model add:

```
TaskType.TasksTypes = TaskType.hasMany(models.TasksTypes, {
  as: 'tasksRelations',
  foreignKey: 'typeId',
  hooks: true,
  onDelete: 'cascade'
})
```